What is this trim part from a slider door sill called?
There is a white vinyl piece that is removeable from the door frame that has warped over time. I have searched trying to figure out what it is called so I can try to find a replacement. No luck with Sill or Threshold parts. And the Manufacturer Code I can't find any google results for either. Any pointers would be appreciated. (I promise to clean up when I get the new part)
The raised white threshold piece is 1.5" x 34".

Manufacturer Code: SW-1, Series: 1000 / SGD-C20 MST: 10080

Mfr Code: SW-1.

Series: 1000    /   SGD-C20      MST: 10080

Who is the manufacturer?  It is probably proprietary to them, and looks alot like a trim piece in the sill of my Pella sliders.

I put the Manufacturer code from the sticker above in the comments. But the Google search engine doesn't return any useful information about 'SW-1'. It is a builder install from the late 1990s, so something cheap from that era.

Based on some Googling, that may be a Milgard door.  Perhaps reach out to them.

I reached out to Milguard. will update when they respond.

AFAICT it's just a threshold "spacer" to make the step-over as flush as practical—instead of the flanges sticking up and being a hazard to bare feet and tripping.  You should be able to remove it and perhaps use a heat gun to straighten it out (if you can't find a replacement).

I guess that makes sense. I'm surprised that I can't find such a part in google search.
